# Chat box Dialog style Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a simple chat app. I am using `Text View` to display messages. It all works fine. I need to add a little arrow like we get in dialog boxes.

[This is what I am talking about. That little triangle shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQPj2.png)

how can this be achieved???

Comment: just create a triangle image and attach it with your textview using relativelayout.

Comment: is this the only solution that I can perform? I was wondering if its possible to create the shape then use it as a background for the textbox??

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9 patch image and set it as background of your message layout.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this without using an image??

Comment: for triangle you have to create an image and the next rectangle message area you can create it by using xml file

Comment: You can create your custom background using xml